# Object expected in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, object-expected

Of all the solutions i have seen for this they fall into 3 categories.

- Syntax or mispelling.
- Using a type other than text/javascript.
- Having two or more id with the same name.

I have none of these issues and i get an error on the process table data call.

What do i need to do so this will work in Internet Explorer.  Firefox and others do work.

```
window.onload=function() {
  ProcessTableData();
  mapzoom.add(document.getElementById('UtCounties'),{buttons:false,fading:true}); 
}
```

As requested here is the full and complete code.  Please dont mention the html tag or doctype as the content management system (WebEoc - ESI) takes care of that.  Pleases dont mention any tags that refer to eocrepeatallrecords as those are cms specific.  What it does there is build a table of which i consume and set options for the mapzoom product via the calssname.

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Image Map Dispaly</title>
<style>

table{font-size:11px;font-family:Sans-serif;}
.TableTitle{text-align:center; font-size:15px;}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/mapzoom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload=function() {

    ProcessTableData();
    mapzoom.add(document.getElementById('UtCounties'),{buttons:false,fading:true}); 

}
</script>




</head>
<body>

<table id="eocTable"><!--  style="display:none;" <attribute name="bgColor">#<value-of select="/data/listitems[@listname='Activation Status' and @name=current()/@status]/@listvalue"></value-of></attribute> -->
<eocrepeatallrecords sort="County_Select, initial_datetime desc"><!-- Changing the order or structure between the eocrepeatallrecords tag will cause errors in the script. -->
<tr>
<td width="70px"><eocfield name="County_Select"></eocfield></td>
<td width="20px"><eocfield name="status"></eocfield></td>
<td style="display:none;"><value-of select="/data/listitems[@listname='Activation Status' and @name=current()/@status]/@listvalue"></value-of></td>
<td selected="true"><eocfield name="initial_datetime"></eocfield></td>
</tr>
</eocrepeatallrecords>
</table>


<table border="1" id="mainTable">
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<p class="TableTitle">County Activation Status</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table id="displayTable" border="1">
<tr><td width="70px">Beaver</td><td width="20px"></td><td style="display:none;"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td width="70px">Box Elder</td><td width="20px"></td><td style="display:none;"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td width="70px">Cache</td><td width="20px"></td><td style="display:none;"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td width="70px">Carbon</td><td width="20px"></td><td style="display:none;"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td width="70px">Daggett</td><td width="20px"></td><td style="display:none;"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td width="70px">Davis</td><td width="20px"></td><td style="display:none;"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td width="70px">Duchesne</td><td width="20px"></td><td style="display:none;"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td width="70px">Emery</td><td width="20px"></td><td style="display:none;"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td width="70px">Garfield</td><td width="20px"></td><td style="display:none;"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td width="70px">Grand</td><td width="20px"></td><td style="display:none;"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td width="70px">Iron</td><td width="20px"></td><td style="display:none;"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td width="70px">Juab</td><td width="20px"></td><td style="display:none;"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td width="70px">Kane</td><td width="20px"></td><td style="display:none;"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td width="70px">Millard</td><td width="20px"></td><td style="display:none;"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td width="70px">Morgan</td><td width="20px"></td><td style="display:none;"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td width="70px">Piute</td><td width="20px"></td><td style="display:none;"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td width="70px">Rich</td><td width="20px"></td><td style="display:none;"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td width="70px">Salt Lake</td><td width="20px"></td><td style="display:none;"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td width="70px">San Juan</td><td width="20px"></td><td style="display:none;"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td width="70px">San Pete</td><td width="20px"></td><td style="display:none;"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td width="70px">Sevier</td><td width="20px"></td><td style="display:none;"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td width="70px">Summit</td><td width="20px"></td><td style="display:none;"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td width="70px">Tooele</td><td width="20px"></td><td style="display:none;"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td width="70px">Uintah</td><td width="20px"></td><td style="display:none;"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td width="70px">Utah</td><td width="20px"></td><td style="display:none;"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td width="70px">Wasatch</td><td width="20px"></td><td style="display:none;"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td width="70px">Washington</td><td width="20px"></td><td style="display:none;"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td width="70px">Wayne</td><td width="20px"></td><td style="display:none;"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td width="70px">Weber</td><td width="20px"></td><td style="display:none;"></td><td></td></tr>
</table>

</td>

<td><div>
<!-- /UTAHSS-1/plugins/filestore/getfile.ashx?fileid=1336" usemap="#UtCounties" id="mapImg -->
<img src="/UTAHSS-1/plugins/filestore/getfile.ashx?fileid=1336" usemap="#UtCounties" id="UtCounties" border="0"></img>
</div>

<map id="UtCounties" name="UtCounties">

<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="8,432,9,389,128,393,128,400,135,407,135,409,141,416,140,425,138,429,130,433" /><!-- Beaver -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="20,48,162,51,172,71,170,76,171,83,173,96,179,97,182,105,176,109,171,117,155,116,136,142,114,148,18,147" /><!-- Box Elder -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="210,51,160,51,173,71,172,75,169,79,172,84,173,90,172,96,182,103,181,109,192,112,200,109,208,108,215,94,215,81,210,67,212,60,212,58" /><!-- Cache -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="227,270,326,269,330,272,325,278,323,284,321,293,322,303,242,303,235,292,228,278" /><!-- Carbon -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="323,150,393,148,395,184,387,182,382,165,370,164,370,171,362,177,358,169,343,171,333,173,322,169" /><!-- Daggett -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="190,164,182,137,161,135,134,142,152,174,172,158,175,169" /><!-- Davis -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="325,271,324,170,302,168,283,176,267,177,263,181,256,179,255,258,258,262,259,270" /><!-- Duchesne -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="324,399,325,388,321,383,315,379,318,373,312,357,314,351,323,356,322,350,313,347,315,339,319,328,319,319,323,311,323,303,242,303,228,280,228,304,224,304,223,399" /><!-- Emery -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="131,434,332,434,323,438,320,448,315,447,310,454,310,459,294,461,290,470,288,482,282,486,279,494,275,495,114,494,114,468,124,468,124,458,133,458" /><!-- Garfield -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="325,401,325,395,323,391,317,379,319,376,311,359,314,357,314,352,323,357,323,351,314,348,316,335,320,327,318,322,323,312,323,303,391,302,397,301,398,399" /><!-- Grand -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="8,431,131,434,131,460,123,460,121,469,113,469,113,494,98,495,97,498,69,501,67,495,51,493,50,485,6,486" /><!-- Iron -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="13,256,13,292,154,294,155,316,166,317,172,315,177,312,191,311,192,303,193,282,201,278,201,269,186,271,189,263,183,256,169,271,163,272,165,259,158,250,142,259" /><!-- Juab -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="96,549,95,494,276,496,275,500,269,501,272,506,267,508,269,513,262,517,258,514,257,519,256,529,251,536,239,538,234,540,228,545,225,543,221,549" /><!-- Kane -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="12,293,153,295,154,316,168,318,169,344,164,353,158,357,156,363,152,365,152,378,143,382,133,381,130,393,9,389" /><!-- Millard -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="222,138,231,136,227,131,225,120,217,115,211,130,203,128,196,132,186,128,183,139,186,156,190,165,200,171,206,172,211,169,207,158,202,154,207,147,216,143" /><!-- Morgan -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="180,435,180,409,189,399,129,397,133,408,137,410,142,414,138,425,141,429,133,433" /><!-- Piute -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="211,51,244,51,243,127,230,136,227,127,224,117,216,115,209,109,217,88,210,67,212,59" /><!-- Rich -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="153,173,173,158,175,168,189,165,199,169,202,182,204,192,201,194,195,199,190,199,174,209,168,206,164,208,158,204" /><!-- SaltLake -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="322,400,399,399,402,548,219,549,234,540,246,538,255,532,258,515,267,517,270,510,270,502,274,501,281,491,286,482,291,472,293,461,309,458,316,448,327,437,334,429,330,418,323,409" /><!-- SanJuan -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="169,346,168,318,173,316,177,313,190,312,192,303,191,284,202,277,202,270,227,269,228,305,224,304,223,347" /><!-- Sanpete -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="223,399,224,346,169,346,166,353,162,353,159,358,152,364,152,376,148,381,133,382,128,397" /><!-- Sevier -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="323,150,245,152,243,152,243,126,232,135,221,137,216,142,208,145,204,154,207,156,212,167,208,173,200,171,203,180,204,190,211,189,215,183,220,189,233,196,239,193,247,195,252,184,256,177,262,182,267,177,287,175,304,169,323,171" /><!-- Summitt -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="13,256,18,147,113,149,134,141,156,183,158,201,155,205,158,216,160,233,157,251,145,259" /><!-- Tooele -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="325,171,334,174,359,169,361,177,369,173,369,164,382,165,384,171,387,184,395,186,397,298,393,302,323,303,322,293,326,276,332,270,325,269" /><!-- Uintah -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="258,269,256,260,242,259,231,247,229,235,225,224,215,222,214,218,207,216,202,207,204,194,197,198,191,198,175,209,169,204,165,207,156,204,158,217,158,226,161,233,157,241,159,248,162,253,162,258,165,265,165,272,173,267,185,257,190,266,188,269" /><!-- Utah -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="256,260,255,179,249,191,238,194,236,196,220,188,217,184,210,190,204,187,203,196,201,208,206,217,213,218,214,222,225,224,231,238,229,246,239,257,244,261" /><!-- Wasatch -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="6,485,50,485,50,493,68,495,69,500,79,500,86,500,98,499,95,549,3,547" /><!-- Washington -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="187,399,323,400,326,401,325,407,329,412,334,427,332,433,272,433,180,434,182,408" /><!-- Wayne -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="204,128,212,126,215,115,209,109,195,107,191,113,177,109,173,116,153,117,137,141,160,135,182,136,187,127,196,133" /><!-- Weber -->
<!-- Cutout -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="255,50,255,2,317,2,317,6,309,4,308,14,302,17,280,17" /><!-- BoxElder2 -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="316,2,357,2,357,6,352,5,342,7,335,6,332,13,321,8" /><!-- Cache2 -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="254,51,283,43,307,42,310,44,320,45,322,60,328,69,325,70,332,85,320,88,311,88,309,75,302,75,277,97" /><!-- Davis2 -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="400,33,400,2,357,2,356,6,366,13,373,13,382,22,381,32,385,33,385,44" /><!-- Rich2 -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="350,117,348,124,338,129,312,140,306,145,299,141,284,137,285,118,277,97,302,75,308,75,308,85,312,89,333,84,340,85,343,96" /><!-- SaltLake2 -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="400,33,400,120,396,127,373,116,368,113,368,109,364,109,360,114,358,120,351,118,344,100,342,90,350,94,356,92,359,85,356,70,348,68,348,64,353,58,364,53,369,52,373,47,387,43" /><!-- Summitt -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="282,146,280,140,285,138,284,121,281,104,254,53,255,146" /><!-- Tooele2 -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="349,146,345,143,349,137,347,125,336,129,315,137,307,145,300,139,285,139,281,139,283,146" /><!-- Utah2 -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="401,122,401,146,349,146,345,143,347,137,348,124,350,118,360,120,364,108,370,108,378,118,387,123,394,126" /><!-- Wasatch -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="255,51,280,16,302,16,308,14,309,5,312,6,318,5,327,10,331,12,336,6,356,6,365,14,364,21,361,29,357,32,353,30,347,32,345,36,335,38,330,34,326,35,318,40,321,45,309,43,283,44" /><!-- Weber -->
<area shape="poly" title="" alt="" href="#" coords="333,84,325,69,329,69,322,57,321,45,319,38,329,34,335,38,343,36,347,31,353,31,358,32,366,14,370,13,378,17,382,24,382,32,385,34,385,44,373,45,368,53,353,58,347,68,353,71,359,84,356,94,349,93,333,83" /><!-- Morgan -->

</map>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">

var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("area");

function ProcessTableData()
{
alert(mapzoom.version);



// alert(document.getElementById("eocTable").rows.length);
total = document.getElementById("eocTable").rows.length;
// alert("Rows = " + document.getElementsByTagName("tr").length);
var county = new Array(); 
var act = new Array(); 
var useColor = new Array();
var timeInfo = new Array();
var myColor ="";

for(var count = 0; count &lt; total; count++)
{

countyName = document.getElementById("eocTable").rows[count].childNodes[0].textContent;
actStatus = document.getElementById("eocTable").rows[count].childNodes[1].textContent;
myColor = document.getElementById("eocTable").rows[count].childNodes[2].textContent;
time = document.getElementById("eocTable").rows[count].childNodes[3].textContent;

county[count] = countyName;
act[count] = actStatus;
useColor[count] = "pacolor" + myColor;
timeInfo[count] = time;

} // end for

// filter duplicates
for(var i = 1; i &lt; county.length; ){
if(county[i-1] == county[i]){
// alert("1 = " + county[i-1] + " 2 = " + county[i] + i);
// alert("1 = " + county[i-1] + " " + act[i-1] + " " + useColor[i-1] + " " + timeInfo[i-1]);

county.splice(i, 1);
act.splice(i, 1);
useColor.splice(i, 1);
timeInfo.splice(i, 1);
} else {  
i++;
}  
} 


initializeMap(county, act, useColor, timeInfo);

minwidth = document.getElementById("mainTable").offsetWidth;
minheight = document.getElementById("mainTable").offsetHeight;

} // end process Table Data

function initializeMap(county, act, useColor, timeInfo)
{
countyIndex = ["Beaver", "Box Elder", "Cache", "Carbon", "Daggett", "Davis", "Duchesne", "Emery", "Garfield", "Grand", "Iron", "Juab", "Kane", "Millard", "Morgan", "Piute", "Rich", "Salt Lake", "San Juan", "San Pete", "Sevier", "Summit", "Tooele", "Uintah", "Utah", "Wasatch", "Washington", "Wayne", "Weber"];
myTable = document.getElementById('displayTable');
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("area");

for(count = 0; count &lt; county.length - 1; count++)
{

//alert("first County = " + county[count] +  "Activation = " + act[count] + "Count = " + count);

if (county[count].indexOf("County") &gt; -1)
{
count++;
}
for(i = 0; i &lt; countyIndex.length - 1; i++)
{
if (county[count].indexOf(countyIndex[i]) &gt; -1)
{
//useColor[count]
//"specified pacolor00aa00 paopacity33 vaopacity0 noborder

tags[i].className = "specified " + useColor[count] + " paopacity33 vaopacity0 noborder";
myTable.rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "#" + useColor[count].slice(7,13);
myTable.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML = act[count];
myTable.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML = timeInfo[count];


}
}
}// end for

}// end function

</script>
</body>
</html>

<table id="eocTable">
<tr>
            <td width="70px"><font style="background-color:#;">Beaver&nbsp;</font>&nbsp;</span></td>
            <td width="20px"><font style="background-color:#4640ff;">2&nbsp;</font>&nbsp;</span></td>
            <td style="display: none;">4640ff</td>
            <td selected="true">10/27/2011 14:34:52&nbsp;</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td width="70px"><font style="background-color:#;">Beaver&nbsp;</font>&nbsp;</span></td>
            <td width="20px"><font style="background-color:#e00b00;">3&nbsp;</font>&nbsp;</span></td>
            <td style="display: none;">e00b00</td>
            <td selected="true">10/27/2011 14:34:40&nbsp;</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td width="70px"><font style="background-color:#;">Kane&nbsp;</font>&nbsp;</span></td>
            <td width="20px"><font style="background-color:#4640ff;">2&nbsp;</font>&nbsp;</span></td>
            <td style="display: none;">4640ff</td>
            <td selected="true">11/01/2011 09:17:40&nbsp;</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td width="70px"><font style="background-color:#;">Piute&nbsp;</font>&nbsp;</span></td>
            <td width="20px"><font style="background-color:#e00b00;">3&nbsp;</font>&nbsp;</span></td>
            <td style="display: none;">e00b00</td>
            <td selected="true">11/01/2011 09:17:05&nbsp;</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td width="70px"><font style="background-color:#;">San Juan&nbsp;</font>&nbsp;</span></td>
            <td width="20px"><font style="background-color:#f0ec00;">1&nbsp;</font>&nbsp;</span></td>
            <td style="display: none;">f0ec00</td>
            <td selected="true">10/27/2011 14:35:00&nbsp;</span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td width="70px"><font style="background-color:#;">Wayne&nbsp;</font>&nbsp;</span></td>
            <td width="20px"><font style="background-color:#4640ff;">2&nbsp;</font>&nbsp;</span></td>
            <td style="display: none;">4640ff</td>
            <td selected="true">11/01/2011 09:16:54&nbsp;</span></td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How could we possibly solve this for you without seeing the actual code that causes the problem, probably in a page that works in other browsers?  This is a matter of debugging, either examining appropriate error messages or tracing through the code in IE to see what's going wrong.  This is elementary debugging.  You don't solve this with conjecture.  You get in their with debugging tools on actual code and see what's wrong.

Comment: Auctually the code you are seeing is the where the error occurs.  The call to ProcessTableData(); is the line mentioned in the error.

Comment: This an insufficient amount of code to see where the problem might be and it is unlikely that either of these lines of code are directly causing the error.  Use a debugger, set breakpoints, find where the error really is and why.

Comment: If you feel you need more info to answer please add a comment rather than downvote.  Keep in mind the code is 3 pages mixed in with html along with some cms specific code.

Comment: I didn't downvote, though if you don't add more info to the question, I probably will vote to close as unanswerable.  I've commented plenty and told you what you need to do.  Do you know how to use a javascript debugger?  That's how you solve this.

Comment: I have done some elementary debugging.  The debugger skips over the functions.  It wont even let me see any of the variables.  What i gather from the debugging is the same thing i get from loading the page it is skipping a function.  Why is it skipping the process table data function.

Comment: If the error you are getting refers to the `ProcessTableData()` call then presumably the error is somewhere inside that function. Without seeing the code for that function it is difficult to help. (I admit I'm not overly keen to go through 3 pages of code, but if you show it somebody might help; if you don't show it nobody can help.)

Comment: I just Added the full code.  I will greatly appreciate any helpful comments and suggestions.  I know its alot of code.  I have alot riding on this and i will show my gratitude by supporting this community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE did not like the fact that i was using .childNodes[0].textContent; to retrieve the info from the table that was generated by the cms.  Nothing was being grabbed and as a result everything went null.  Once i used innerhtml (yes some people warn against it I will update it later) it worked in IE and firefox.  I did need to filter some of the html off of it.

If anyone is interested in the final code send me a message.  Perhaps later this month i will have time to revamp this script.

Answer (score 1):

I've placed your code into [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/msD4y/) where I can attempt to run it and debug it.

I can see these issues in the code you have included:

1. You have multiple javascript coding errors where `&gt;` appears instead of `>` and `&lt;` appears instead of `<` in your javascript comparisons.   All those have to get fixed before the code will even run.
2. The code starts to run OK after fixing those errors, but we don't have access to mapzoom.js so I have to comment out any references to it.
3. In IE9 (and only in IE9), I find that early on in the `ProcessTableData()` function, the total value is zero which causes the first loop to do nothing.  This only occurs in IE9.  In Chrome, total is 1 when that loop starts.  This appears to be because of the non-standard HTML you have in `oecTable` HTML.  Remove that non-standard stuff (e.g. make it look like normal table HTML with no unusual tags in the HTML) and that code starts working again.

Since I have no idea what your code is supposed to actually do, that's all I can see so far.  If you want to provide more info on what it's supposed to do or what else you need help with, perhaps we can help further.

Comment: The &gt; and &lt; are required by the cms as to not mistake < and > for tags and xml.  Its a quirk of this cms.  should of mentioned that my apologies.  Googling mapzoom.js or visiting this site netzgesta.de/mapzoom will get you mapzoom.js.  Please see my next comment as i will be adding to this.

Comment: I took the code out of the cms.  repaired all of the < and > added a proper html table of which you will find at the bottom of my code i just edited.  I now have a functioning debugger that doesnt hide code from me or crash etc.

Comment: The first thing i noticed is wierd.  the total variable was not listed however the loop still ran. many of the var are not shown.  The mycolor becomes undefined after the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: That's because the total variable is not declared as a local variable with `var` so it's treated as an implicit global variable (a bad thing).  The debugger just shows local variables by default.

Comment: it is as if none of the statements that consume the info out of the table are doing anything.  At the end of a debug nearly everything was undefined.  Have you ever came across something like this before. eoctable is sample of what i get as that is what's given by the cms.  Is there a better way to pull that info out of the table?   The short version of what i am trying to accomplish is consume and store info from the eoctable.  Second filter and remove duplicates.

Comment: This is what the mapzoom feeds off of for the options related to the various areas.

Comment: I told you in my post that the non-standard tags in the table HTML are messing up the parsing of the table to IE doesn't get the info in the table.  Get rid of the non-standard tags in the table and it seems to work for me.

Comment: Exactly which non standard tags are you referring too?

Comment: `<eocrepeatallrecords sort="County_Select, initial_datetime desc">` and `</eocrepeatallrecords>`

Comment: Please remove the <eocrepeatallrecords tag.  Review my original post as i have edited it.  Towards the bottom is a sample eoctable that you need to put in place of the <eocrepeatallrecords tags.